# How to convert jarirreader format to PDF/Mobi

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers, conversion

I do have a book extension is .jarirreader from https://jarirreader.com/

However I can't read / convert the book unless i open it with there app. 
here is the book structure. 
[image: book structure]

Images contains the cover / index has Json format / Text has chapters with HTML extension.

Comment: Can you upload an example?

Comment: here is one. 

[book 9150.jarrireader](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13oTyXBG5TmfCnwxHksvsEBHcK21cMYSD/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a custom format with [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management)ed and/or obfuscated files. Try opening the files in the text folder with a web browser. If you can read them in a browser you can re-assemble them to a book with an epub editor.

Comment: I have tried to do so , however there are unkown symbols. I tried to use chrome translate to arabic , and some text appeard and the rest are unknown

Comment: In that case the files in the book are most likely obfuscated. I.e., there's nothing you can do, unless you're a programmer with excellent reverse engineering skills.